# How to put Javafx program online?

Tags: javafx

Whhat are the best free websites where I can host my javafx application using the files (.jar .jpln .html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is [Amazon S3 static website hosting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html).

Determining the best free hosting site is relative and unanswerable in general.